# I have two models try to render a model product on a view page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two models one being `places` and `blogs`.

I want to be able to render the `blogs.title` on the `places.index.html` page.

When I call `<%= place.blogs.title %>` I get:

> NoMethodError in Places#index

This is the controller where I am calling all the places in the `index`:

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @places = Place.all
  end
end
```

This is my first model for `place`:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
end
```

This is my second model for `blog`:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :place
  validates_presence_of :title, :body
end
```

And this is the index page I am trying to render:

```
<h1>Place index with blogs</h1>

<% @places.each do |place| %>
  <%= place.country %>
  <%= place.state %>
  <%= place.blogs.title %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`place.blogs` is a Relation object containing all `Blog`s that are related to this particular `Place`.

You need to tell ActiveRecord to pull down all the related `Blog` records in your query, so that it can do that in the minimum number of requests. This is called [**eager loading**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @places = Place.includes(:blogs).all
  end
end
```

Next, add an inner loop to your template

```
<h1>Place index with blogs</h1>

<% @places.each do |place| %>
  <%= place.country %>
  <%= place.state %>
  <ul>
    <% place.blogs.each do |blog| %>
      <li><%= blog.title %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

The inner loop will appear to work on its own without using `includes`, but this will result in launching new requests against the DB each loop, which is a serious performance problem.